# SurfaceView unnecessary redrawings

Tags: android, surfaceview

I need to write finger paint application. I need some computations about the drawn curve, so I think it's a good idea to use `SurfaceView` but not `View`.

I've written code for drawing. I collect the points into Path and draw it. On ACTION_UP this Path is reseting. And in the drawing loop I draw only the last Path.

But for some reason previous paths are redrawn too. This cause annoying blinking, which I don't want. I've changing line color on every draw cycle and I see, that previous paths change their colors, despite of there is no code to collect and redraw them.

Why so? Is there any way to make SurfaceView not to repeat all previous drawings?

Here is my code:

```
public class OtherDrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private DrawingThread mThread;

    private Path mPath;

    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public OtherDrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        mThread = new DrawingThread(surfaceHolder);

        mPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                continueDrawingThread();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                continueDrawingThread();
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mPath.reset();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mThread.setRunning(true);
        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        mThread.setRunning(false);
        continueDrawingThread();

        while (retry) {
            try {
                mThread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
        }
    }

    private void continueDrawingThread() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.notifyAll();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        }
    }

    private class DrawingThread extends Thread {
        private boolean mRunning;

        private Paint mPaint;
        private Random mRandom = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        private final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

        public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            mRunning = running;
        }

        private void drawPath() {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    assert canvas != null;

                    mPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(mRandom.nextInt(255), mRandom.nextInt(255), mRandom.nextInt(255)));
                    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) { }
            finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (mRunning) {
                drawPath();

                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't understand why `SurfaceView` behaves like this, but I've found a workaround: draw not directly on canvas but on some bitmap and then output this bitmap on main canvas. Fully described in this article: http://android-coding.blogspot.ru/2012/01/flickering-problems-due-to-double.html

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas):

"After this call, the surface's current pixels will be shown on the screen, but its content is lost, in particular there is no guarantee that the content of the Surface will remain unchanged when lockCanvas() is called again."

So, when drawing to a surface view, you always have to clear the background (normally by re-drawing a background image) before drawing anything else on top, eg. the path in your case.